# Getting ID from ListView item when clicking a checkbox

Tags: android, listview, checkbox

I use a ListView with a custom adapter to build a list with ckeckboxes. Now I dont know how i can fetch the "ID" from the selected box.

The xml file for the items look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="5dp">
    <TextView android:id="@+id/class_open"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:visibility="gone" />
    <CheckBox   
        android:id="@+id/checkbox"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true" 
        android:onClick="clickHandler" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/medi_name"
        android:text="Test"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/checkbox" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

I need the value from: "class_open"

this is my activity:

```
package de.bodprod.dkr;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MediNotmediUserListNew extends Activity{
    LayoutInflater inflater;
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>> medi_notmedi_items;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.medi_notmedi_user_list_new);

        ListView mediListCheck = (ListView) findViewById(android.R.id.list);
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        medi_notmedi_items = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,Object>>();
        SystemDatabaseHandler db = new SystemDatabaseHandler(getApplicationContext());
        medi_notmedi_items = db.getAllNotmedis(); 

        final CustomAdapter adapter = new CustomAdapter(this, R.layout.medi_notmedi_user_list_new, medi_notmedi_items);
        mediListCheck.setAdapter(adapter);

    }

    public void clickHandler(View view) {

    }


    private class CustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<HashMap<String, Object>>{
        public CustomAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId, ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>> Strings) {
            super(context, textViewResourceId, Strings);
        }
        private class ViewHolder{
            TextView class_open, title;
        }
        ViewHolder viewHolder;

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            if(convertView==null){        
                convertView=inflater.inflate(R.layout.medi_notmedi_user_list_new_item, null);
                viewHolder=new ViewHolder();
                viewHolder.class_open=(TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.class_open);
                viewHolder.title=(TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.medi_name);
                convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
            }else{
                viewHolder=(ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
            }
            viewHolder.class_open.setText(medi_notmedi_items.get(position).get("sql_id").toString());
            viewHolder.title.setText(medi_notmedi_items.get(position).get("wirk").toString());
            return convertView;
        }
    }       
}
```

How I can get the value from the class_open field in the clickHandler?

1. Is it possible to assign the value directly to the checkbox and request it?
2. Is it possible to request the value from the class_open field?

Please excuse my bad english

Markus

Comment: on click of the checkbox you need the value of the textview corresponding to it, is this you are trying to acheive

Comment: Yes, I need the value of the textview class-open which corresponding to the checkbox or a possibility how I can assign the value directly to the checkbox and use it in the clickHandler.

Comment: are you able to get the positions of the items you have checked

Comment: Hey you cant do it with the clickhandler method by defining it in the xml, in the CustomAdapter  class get the instance of the checkbox and create an click listner inside the adapter